# How to remove fragment parmently in tab fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I build project for manually swipe tab using `viewpager` and `TabFragment`.I have still error couple of week, When i remove item from `viewpager` and `tab` then its success but when i create new item then previous removed item show me again at the same position. What can i do? Please give me best regards, My project going to be late. Here my code below.

Remove button code :

```
 btCloseTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(COUNT_TAB>0) {// Check first count tab is 1 and more
                if(TAB_CURRENT>=0 && PAGE_CURRENT>=0) {  //Check Tab currunt and page curunt value is grater then equal to 0


                     try {
                        viewPager.removeViewAt(PAGE_CURRENT);
                        actionBar.removeTabAt(TAB_CURRENT); 
                        COUNT_TAB -= 1;   
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        viewPager.destroyDrawingCache();



                         my_tabList_array.remove(PAGE_CURRENT);
                         iTabListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                         TAB_TAG-=1;


                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

My Adapter class

```
public class TabsPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {



    public TabsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        /*Fragment fragment = new SwipClass();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(SwipClass.ARG_TAB_POSITION, i);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;*/

        return new SwipClass();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return COUNT_TAB;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment)object).getFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment)object);
        trans.commit();
    }
}
```

When i add tab then i used this code

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("New Tabs").setTag(""+TAB_TAG)
                    .setTabListener(HomeActivity.this));
```

Kindly please give me best regards and answer for this, Thanks in advance